# Facebook Like counts the same for multiple Wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, facebook, plugins, facebook-like

I have a website that runs on wordpress...

It uses the Facebook Wordpress plugin to generate like buttons and counts at the bottom of every post.

The problem is many posts have the same like count - a quick look at the home page shows multiple posts with the same count of 2780 - a number that isn't at all possible after being online only a day. Some other posts have correct counts (less than 10), but cannot work out why this very high count is attached to multiple posts.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Try a different plugin?

Comment: Just tried 3 different like button plugins - all pulling same 2780 like count for multiple posts. Data must be coming from Facebook then as opposed to the site?

Comment: Or the way the plugin is configured?  Maybe pulling likes for site vs posts.

Comment: any way to check that? The plugin configuration is so simple I don't feel that is the problem here. All you do is add your app id and app secret. If I delete a post with the problem, then create an identical post to replace - the issue is solved, but i can't do that for hundreds of posts...

Comment: I just remember with share this and Pinterest plugins, not wp, I had issues with how the plugin picked up the data.  Home page vs page vs post etc.  sorry I can't be more help, but when you click like/share does it share the correct URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at some of your site's pages in the [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), and look to see if multiple pages return the same "canonical url".

If they do, Facebook considers these to be the same page, and will aggregate their likes and other data. Check the source of these pages to make sure that there is only one unique `og:url` tag and if there is a `<link rel="canonical">` tag, it points to that content's unique permalink, not your homepage.

Lots of WordPress plugins add open graph meta tags these days, including some you wouldn't expect.

Comment: This seems to have been the problem. Source shows two sets of Facebook OG meta tags - one with the correct permalink, and another with a general site url (for the root/home page).
Thanks very much for you help!